# How to use OR and AND operation in yml file?

Tags: java, yaml

I have a `.yml` file where I want to use an `AND` operant between a `Boolean` and another equal statement as below. I use this `.yml` file in `Java`.

```
requires: (foo.advance) && (foo.midi == "ON_GOING_MIDI")
```

**How can I do it in correct way in .yml file?**

```
menu: admin
  sub:
    - view: magazine 
      icon: "tiles"
      requires:foo.advance
    - view: factor 
     icon: "icon2"
      requires:not(foo.advance)
    - view: usages 
      requires: (foo.advance) && (foo.midi == "ON_GOING_MIDI")
- menu: user
```

Comment: YAML is just a text file so you can put anything you like in the .yml

Comment: You can't add conditions to a yml file its just a text formatting way, not a language. But still, you can load the yml file into a programming language and can apply if else to it. based on a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I use [eo-yaml](https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml)
lib in my project. I added the following in the `.yml` file and used it in `Java code`.

```
 requires: ${foo.advance && foo.midi == "ON_GOING_MIDI"}
```

As @flyx suggested it is also possible to use `SnakeYAML` library.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, YAML is not a programming language and generally doesn't provide operators you can use.

However, YAML does provide *tags* that instruct the loading code about the kind of a node. So you can write this:

```yaml
requires: !and [foo.advance, !eq [foo.midi, "ON_GOING_MIDI"] ]
```

Which, from a YAML view, is a sequence containing two items, the first being `foo.advance` while the second is a nested sequence. The outer sequence has the tag `!and` while the inner one has the tag `!eq`.

You can the write code loading this YAML which knows about `!and` and `!eq` and processes them appropriately. For Java, SnakeYAML is a popular option which lets you [define custom constructors](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, indeed it is a very nice lib to use as I have gone deep into it I see it is a very rich lib. Unfortunately, I have already eo-yaml lib in my project and I am not allowed to change it.
https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml

Comment: That library seems very immature. No support for anchors and aliases, no support for tags either. If you can't change it, your only option is to have a post-processor that parses some syntax/structure you define.